# How to maintain position in scrollable view when elements load above the current position?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I have a react-native SectionList that contains multiple FlatLists in the view. When a user touches one of the elements in the bottom FlatList, some of the FlatLists above will load new data causing the user's current view to seem be pushed up. In other words, the user's y-position remains the same but the content that was previously in view now has a greater y-position.

How can I keep the user's y-position in sync with the elements they had in view before the elements in the other FlatLists above were added?

Comment: Can you post a codesandbox example?

Comment: @Tyler Facing same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: @Balasubramanian, unfortunately shortly after this question, my team redesigned the screen with this problem which made this no longer an issue for us.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to answer without any code example.

Seems `scrollToLocation` method with `animated: false` after data was changed should do the trick.

Comment: Exactly facing the problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330439/flatlist-keep-the-scrollview-content-position-at-same-place)).  Couldn't able to find `scrollToLocation`. Please help me out.

Comment: @Balasubramanian for FlatList you should look at scrollToOffset method. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltooffset