# FlatList - Keep the ScrollView Content Position at same place?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

When click the row extends the content, keep that row position at same place (in same viewport) and show the extended content below.

**Actual Result:**
Right now, its **moving up** the old content above and shows the new content in that position.

**Expected Result:**
I want the **touched row should be at same place** if its extends the row height. So Row should be in the same place where user touched in the screen and they can disable it again by touching in the same position.

How can I achieve this?